# Adding two `csc` sparse matrices of different shapes in python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

So I have two `csc` matrices of different shapes that I need to add together. The matrices look like this:

```
current_flows = (7005, 1001)    50.0
(8259, 1001)    65.0
(14007, 1001)   45.0
(9971, 1002)    80.0
: :
(69003, 211148) 0.0

result_flows = (7005, 1001) 40
(14007, 1001)   20
(9971, 1002)    35
: :
(71136, 71137)  90

final_flows = current_flows + result_flows
```

As illustrated by some of the row and column ID's shown: `(7005, 1001), (14007, 1001), (9971, 1002)` the matrices do have elements in common.  Based on their final row and column ID's though they are of different shape.

I would like to add the two matrices together, while preserving the shape of the larger matrix (`current_flows`) and keeping the values of `current_flows` the same where `result_flows` does not have a row and column ID that matches `current_flows`. So, `final_flows` will have row and column indexes extending to: `(69003, 211148)` even though `result_flows` only extends to `(71136, 71137)`

Thus, I would like my output to be:

```
final_flows =  (7005, 1001) 90.0
(8259, 1001)    65.0
(14007, 1001)   65.0
(9971, 1002)    115.0
: :
(71136, 71137)  90
(69003, 211148) 0.0
```

Let me know if you'd like any further clarification, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining a matrix via `coo`, or the coo style of input, `(data,(row,col))`, duplicate entries are summed.  Creators of stiffness matrices (for pde solutions) often take advantage of this.

This is a function that uses that.  I convert the matrices to `coo` format (if needed), concatenate their attributes, and build a new matrix.

```
def with_coo(x,y):
    x=x.tocoo()
    y=y.tocoo()
    d = np.concatenate((x.data, y.data))
    r = np.concatenate((x.row, y.row))
    c = np.concatenate((x.col, y.col))
    C = sparse.coo_matrix((d,(r,c)))
    return C
```

With @Vadim's examples:

```
In [59]: C_csc=current_flows.tocsc()
In [60]: R_csc=result_flows.tocsc()

In [61]: with_coo(C_csc, R_csc).tocsc().A
Out[61]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  4],
       [ 0, -2,  0],
       [ 3,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

When making timings we have to be careful because format conversion are nontrivial, e.g.

```
In [70]: timeit  C_csc.tocoo()
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 µs per loop

In [71]: timeit  C_csc.todok()
1000 loops, best of 3: 258 µs per loop
```

Vadim's two options

```
def with_dok(x, y):
    for k in y.keys():  # no has_key in py3
        if k in x:
           x[k] += y[k]
        else:
           x[k] = y[k]
    return x

def with_update(x,y):
    x.update((k, v+x.get(k)) for k, v in y.items())
    return x
```

Starting with the `csc` format:

```
In [74]: timeit with_coo(C_csc,R_csc).tocsc()
1000 loops, best of 3: 629 µs per loop

In [76]: timeit with_update(C_csc.todok(),R_csc.todok()).tocsc()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop

In [77]: timeit with_dok(C_csc.todok(),R_csc.todok()).tocsc()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop
```

I'm guessing that my `coo` approach will scale better - but that's just a guess at this point.

Taking conversions out of the picture, the `dok` update looks better.  `y` has only 2 items, and it does not make any copies - it changes `x` directly.

```
In [78]: %%timeit x=C_csc.todok(); y=R_csc.todok()
   ....: with_update(x, y)
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.6 µs per loop

In [79]: %%timeit x=C_csc.tocoo(); y=R_csc.tocoo()
with_coo(x, y)
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 138 µs per loop
```

================

The `__add__` method for `dok_matrix` contains (if `other` is also `dok`).  There's a comment wondering whether they need to check `shape`.

```
       new = dok_matrix(self.shape, dtype=res_dtype)
        new.update(self)
        for key in other.keys():
            new[key] += other[key]
```

[I can get around the `shape` check in `x+y` if I first change the shape of `y`, e.g. `y._shape = x.shape`.  This is kludgy and only works within rational limits of the original shapes.  And might not be faster than the `with_update` approach.  `dok` is more amenable to this sort of shape change than `csr` or `csc`.]

If the `other` is not `dok`, it does `self.tocsc()+other`.

For matching shapes, the summation times are

```
In [91]: timeit current_flows+current_flows
1000 loops, best of 3: 413 µs per loop

In [92]: timeit C_csc+C_csc
1000 loops, best of 3: 223 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert matrices to `dok` class. Then indices and data will be stored as dictionary. Notice, that second matrix `result_flows` shouldn't have values with indices greater than `current_flows` shape.
(Edited, thanks to @hpaulj comment).

```
from scipy import sparse

current_flows = sparse.dok_matrix([[0, 0, 1],
                                   [2, 0, 4],
                                   [0, 0, 0],
                                   [3, 0, 0]]
                                   )

result_flows = sparse.dok_matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                  [-3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                                  [0, -2, 0, 0, 0]]
                                  )

current_flows.update((k, v + current_flows.get(k)) for k, v in result_flows.items())

current_flows.todense()

Out[108]: matrix([[ 0,  0,  1],
                  [-1,  0,  4],
                  [ 0, -2,  0],
                  [ 3,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Your solution looks like it might work, but do know of a way to convert my existing `csc_matrix`'s to the `dok` class?

Comment: In my timings your `update` version is faster.  In other SO questions I found that the dictionary `update` is the fastest way to changes values of a `dok` matrix.  Indexed access to `dok` elements is slow compared to regular dictionary access.

Comment: @Andrew Earl Use `todok`, e.g. `current_flows = current_flows.todok()`  @hpaulj Sorry, my bad, you are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again @VadimShkaberda, I am encountering another problem though.  My matrices are very very large and consequently I get a memory error during the `todense` step.  I still have a few other arithmetic operations to do with these matrices after adding them and I'm wondering whether it might be best just to leave them in `dok` format? @hpaulj do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Andrew Earl You will have required matrix after `current_flows.update(...` step. The line `current_flows.todense()` I've added for just to show output in dense format. Depending on what you want to do further, you can work with `dok` or consider @hpaulj solution with `coo` matrices.

Comment: Thanks @VadimShkaberda, I've ended up using the `coo` matrices