# multiplying `csr` sparse matrices of different sizes python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to multiply two sparse matrices (elementwise) of different sizes.  Here are the matrices:

```
matrix1 = (1, 2)    30.0
(2, 3)  20.0
(4, 5)  10.0
(6, 7)  80

matrix2 = (1, 2)    2.0
(2, 3)  1.0
(4, 5)  5.0
```

As you can see, `matrix1` is larger than `matrix2`.  I need to multiply them such that the elements that are not present in `matrix2` (in this case element `(6, 7)` remains the same.  The output that I need is as follows:

```
final_matrix = (1, 2)   60.0
(2, 3)  20.0
(4, 5)  50.0
(6, 7)  80
```

For the real data that I am working with the matrices are very large.  Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: The matrices don't have to be different sizes the way you've defined the problem...just put a `1` everywhere you don't have a matching entry in the second matrix.  In order to multiply them elementwise, the dimensions of the spare matrices will have to be the same.

Comment: Great, how do you propose I put a `1` everywhere I don't have a matching entry?  Keep in mind my matrices are very large - iterating over them takes a long time.

Comment: I'm tempted to call this a duplicate of your other question about adding matrices of different shape.  The same issues, and potential solutions apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231163/adding-two-csc-sparse-matrices-of-different-shapes-in-python

Comment: I've actually developed a solution on my own using the method from that question.  Will post the answer soon, just testing to make sure.  Based on this would you suggest marking it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dense array it's relatively easy to perform this sort of multiplication.  And fast, since slicing is fast

```
In [453]: x=np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
In [454]: y=np.arange(10,22).reshape(3,4)

In [457]: x[:3,:4] *= y

In [458]: x
Out[458]: 
array([[  0,  11,  24,  39,   4,   5],
       [ 84, 105, 128, 153,  10,  11],
       [216, 247, 280, 315,  16,  17],
       [ 18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23]])
```

With the sparse equivalents

```
In [460]: xM=sparse.csr_matrix(x)
In [462]: yM=sparse.csr_matrix(y)
```

Sliced multiply works:

```
In [468]: z= xM[:3,:4].multiply(yM)   # z.A matches the dense block
```

But we get a warning when trying to assign that value back onto `xM`

```
In [469]: xM[:3,:4] = xM[:3,:4].multiply(yM)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:730: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)

In [471]: xL=sparse.lil_matrix(x)
In [472]: yL=sparse.lil_matrix(y)
In [475]: xL[:3,:4]=xL[:3,:4].multiply(yL)
```

`xL.multiply` code is actually: `return self.tocsr().multiply(other)`

I don't know which combination of formats will most efficient.

[We might get around the csr sparsity warning by recognizing that `xM[:3,:4].multiply(yM)` will have fewer, not more, nonzero elements.  So at least temporarily we could set some values of `xM.data` to 0 without changing the other attributes.    We can clean up later with `eliminate_zeros`.]

---

An alternative to sliced assignment, is to expand `y` to the size of `x`, and perform the full multiplication.  In this case we need to pad `y` with 1's.

The dense version would be:

```
In [478]: z=np.ones_like(x)
In [479]: z[:3,:4]=y
In [480]: x*z
```

With sparse matrices we have to look at the required padding.  If `yM` is just few rows and/or columns smaller than `xM`, I suspect we can efficiently use `sparse.vstack`  and `hstack`.  If there's a lot of padding the result will have lots of nonzero values, so we might as well make the dense `z`.

```
In [503]: zM = sparse.vstack((yM,np.ones((1,4),int)))
In [504]: zM = sparse.hstack((zM,np.ones((4,2),int)))

In [505]: zM.shape
Out[505]: (4, 6)

In [507]: zM.A
Out[507]: 
array([[10, 11, 12, 13,  1,  1],
       [14, 15, 16, 17,  1,  1],
       [18, 19, 20, 21,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]], dtype=int32)

In [511]: xM.multiply(zM).A
Out[511]: 
array([[  0,  11,  24,  39,   4,   5],
       [ 84, 105, 128, 153,  10,  11],
       [216, 247, 280, 315,  16,  17],
       [ 18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23]], dtype=int32)
```

Another way to build this expanded `yM` is with `sparse.bmat`, which makes a new matrix from blocks.  `bmat` works by constructing `coo` format matrices and concatenating all of their `row, col, data` attributes, and making a new matrix from that.

As it turns out `vstack` uses `bmat`

```
return bmat([[b] for b in blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
```

This constructs the same 4x6 matrix:

```
In [520]: zM = sparse.bmat([[yM, np.ones((3,2),int)],
                  [np.ones((1,4),int), np.ones((1,2),int)]])
```

=================

Another possibility is to adapt @Vadim's `dok` approach from the `sum` problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37241977/901925

It's iterative and highly dependent on the number of nonzero elements of the smaller matrix - but it is quite flexible.

Comment: On further thought, the padding of `y` does not need to be all 1s; just 1s corresponding to the nonzero elements of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more pythonic way to do this, but mathematically, this is a pretty simple approach.

```
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix, lil_matrix, find

## create example matrices, A, B, assume B has values that are not in A
A = csc_matrix( (5,5) )
A[1,1] = 3.0
A[2,2] = 2.0
B = csc_matrix( (5,5) )
B[1,1] = 5.0
B[2,2] = 10.0
B[3,3] = 50.0

C = lil_matrix( (5,5) )  ## C will be a modification of A; 
## more efficient to do this with lil_matrix than csc_matrix; 
## you can convert later if needed

(I,J,V) = find(A)  ## get nonzero indices of A
(M,N,P) = find(B)  ## get nonzero indices of B
C[M,N] = 1.0  ## set all B-corresponding elements to 1.0
C[I,J] = A[I,J]  ## overwrite with corresponding elements in A

D = C.multiply(B)  ## EDIT: per hpaulj's suggestion, using multiply(), which works with most any sparse matrix type
```

Comment: For `csc` matrices of matching size, there's an efficient (compiled) element by element multiplication.  `A.multiply(B)`.